ArgoCD Image Updater skipping my app du to "type of 'Directory'"
Hello, i'm trying to setup ArgoCD Image Updater, but i have this error : 
time="2024-11-01T14:19:53Z" level=warning msg="skipping app 'lumo-backend-app' of type 'Directory' because it's not of supported source type" application=lumo-backend-app
time="2024-11-01T14:19:53Z" level=info msg="Starting image update cycle, considering 0 annotated application(s) for update"
time="2024-11-01T14:19:53Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=0 images_considered=0 images_skipped=0 images_updated=0 errors=0"

It's written that he skipped my app cause it was of type 'Directory' but actually it's not, does i made a mistake somewhere ??
Here is my manifest:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: lumo-backend-app
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: ghcr.io/testlumo/backend
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: 'https://github.com/testlumo/backend.git'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: manifests
  destination:
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    namespace: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true

And the deployment :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lumo-backend
  labels:
    app: lumo-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lumo-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lumo-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: ghcr.io/testlumo/backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ghcr-secret

Btw you can consult the structure of the repository here :
https://github.com/testlumo/backend
Thanks in advance
I tried to redeploy my Application, use ChatGPT and others sources, tried to change the structure of the repo..

If you look at the ArgoCD docs https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.9/user-guide/directory/. Your repo is by definition a directory type

A directory-type application loads plain manifest files from .yml, .yaml, and .json files.


It's unnecessary to explicitly add the spec.source.directory field except to add additional configuration options. Argo CD will automatically detect that the source repository/path contains plain manifest files.

Looking in your manifests folder in your repo it contains only plain yaml files which is what argoCD considers as a directory app since its not Helm or Kustomise.
